# How to copy resources between projects?

Tags: android-studio

There is a drawable resource called `notif.png` (containing 12 png files) that's needed in an other project. CTRL+C, CTRL+V doesn't work.

Comment: Drag and drop doesn't work either.

Comment: None of `Copy`, `Copy Paths`, `Copy as Plain Text`, `Copy Reference` work in the context menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Locate src folder for the project on yout machine: `your-project-name\app\src\main\res`.
2. You can find  `notif.png` in subfolders: `drawable`, `drawable hdpi`, etc.
3. Open  other project's `res` folder & copy those files to correct subfolders.

Comment: Tip: To locate the folder, click `Show in Explorer` in context menu.

Comment: There must be a faster way, instead of doing this manually. Isn't there?

Comment: I tried copying  image from one project to another project  while both projects opened  with android Studio. it worked.   but I'm using windows version of android studio. it might be different if you used  Mac version.  or it might be you have 12  versions of the same png file

Comment: Yes, I have 12 versions of the same file. Also on Windows. (Windows 10, Android Studio 2.2) Thanks, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Doesn't work on Mac. Can't even create the folders from Android Studio on a Mac. Had to create my ldpi, hdpi folders in the mac's finder, then copy the files, in the mac finder from project a to project b. Hopefully some intelligent intellij person will fix this

Answer (score 4):

Switch to "Project" view in the file tree instead of "Android" view in both projects. Then you should be able to copy and paste, and it will convert packages as well.

Screenshot of project view:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My fastest way so far:

1. Click on Resource Manager Tab on the left side (below the Projects
   Tab)
2. Click plus icon (+) then import drawables
3. Search your drawable files with Explorer/Finder and click open

Comment: You can select all the folders in the old project and deselect any drawables you don't want as well. Saved a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

**My easiest way is :**

- **Step 1** : select resources you want to copy
- **Step 2** : open the Resource Manager Tab
- **Step 3** : paste the resource in the Resouce Manager tab
- **Finally** : the Resouce Manager tab shows the import
  drawable for you.

**See the attachment images below....** 
[image: Step 1 : Prepare your copy resources]

[image: Step 2 : Open the Resource Manager Tab]

[image: Step 3 : Your Resources is ready to import !!]

Thank me later